# Mimicking class-based OOP constructors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

**Quick Note:** OOP in Javascript is a topic that is beaten to death on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I cannot find this specific question answered anywhere.

The "hanging code" in Javascript objects has always bothered me, as it seems to break the flow of the code.  What I mean by "hanging code" is the following:

```
function newObject()
{
    var thisObject = this;

    // HANGING CODE DOING VARIOUS THINGS SUCH AS
    // $('#someDiv').click(function(){}); OR
    // var someObjectLiteral = {value:'value'};
}
```

I wanted to mimic class-based OOP constructors by doing the following:

```
function newObject()
{
    var thisObject = this;

    function construct()
    {
        //WHAT USED TO BE HANGING CODE
    }

    construct();
}
```

Is any of the following true or likely to be true about the second methodology:

1. It is significantly slower
2. It will simply not work at all in certain situations
3. It breaks proper coding practice
4. It will be harder to debug
5. There is a superior methodology to achieve the same result

Thank you.

Comment: What is the assignment to a global, `thisObject = this`, supposed to accomplish?

Comment: You're right.  Should be `var thisObject = this;`.  Poor sample code!

Comment: In my opinion your second example is _less_ readable: if you showed me only your second example without any explanation I'd be left wondering why you have a function that is defined and then called immediately but not referenced anywhere else. What you are calling "hanging code" is not really "hanging" because it is already inside a function, and the function it is in _is_ the constructor for your "class". It's still completely OO. The fact that it looks a bit different to a class-based OO language isn't a problem that needs solving because it isn't a problem at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn That is a perfectly fair statement.  It may reflect my lack of familiarity with prototype-based OOP or my over-familiarity with class-based OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the [MooTools Class](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class) which *will* be slower than your method with the 'hanging' code. This is mostly due to the fact that the MooTools Class has overhead associated with their 'Native' structure. A lot of stuff you may not, and will likely not, need. It sounds like you want something straight-to-the-point.

You could do something like:

```
var Klass = function(attrs) {
    var key, newClass;

    attrs = attrs || {};

    newClass = function() {
        if(this.init) {
            this.init.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        }
    };

    for(key in attrs) {
        newClass.prototype[key] = attrs[key]
    }

    return newClass;
};
```

Then, you could do something like:

```
var Person = new Klass({
    init: function(name, bg) {
        this.name = name;
        document.getElementById('container').styles.background = bg;
    },

    speak: function() {
        'I am ' + this.name;
    }
});

var tim = new Person('tim', 'blue');
// background now blue
tim.speak();
// 'I am tim'

var jane = new Person('jane', 'purple');
// background now purple
jane.speak();
// 'I am jane'
```

So, this code will fire off the init() when you make a new instance of a class. Passing it whatever arguments. In which you can put your 'hanging' code. Node that, due to the way prototypes work, this does not allow you to make a new instance of a new instance. And you would need to change it further to allow for things like building off of a parent class. But this is a pretty simple way of building a class structure.

This should work fine for what you want. If you were to come across something it "can't do" there will certainly be a way to correct that. You may just have to finagle the code. As I said in the previous paragraph. There will be a little overhead since a class is basically a function being returned, which you then make a new instance of. But nothing too significant. As for best practices, I would say it is not bad. There are a number of JS libraries that have quite extensive class structures in place for you to use. And a lot of people do use classes. But there are and will be arguments over the use of them since they are not real native JS types.

Comment: BTW I use the var `Klass` since `class` is a reserved word. Even though I could technically use the uppercase `Class` it is probably wise to shy away from it.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong per-se about wrapping code inside an inner function. The only thing you have to watch out is that you can't use `this` inside other functions (you need to use an intermediate variable such as yout `thisObject`.

Having taken that out of the way, **I see no problem at all in having "hanging code"** (at least the kind shown in your example). A language such as Java may have trained you to put *everything* inside a class but in Javascript you only really need to oop-things-up in cases where you explicitly want to take advantage of inheritance or polymorphism.

You probably need to get away from the oop mindset a little. For example, in your case, "hanging code" inside a new object constructor might look bad but I would instead just rename the function to "addClickHandler" or "setLiterals" and call it a day.

Comment: This is a very reasonable point.  I am letting the aesthetics of other languages influence how I code Javascript.  Thanks.

Comment: _"You probably need to get away from the oop mindset a little."_ - JS is still OO, so you want to stay with the OOP mindset. Just remember (as per Vivek's comment) that not all languages do OO the same way.